# how to apply separation logic "lookup" rule

Tags: logic, static-analysis, formal-verification

how can I apply rules of separation logic to find a post condition for the following program? ​

```
k=con(0);  
if(k is even)        
    then i=con(1);        
    else i=con(2);  
j=[i];​
```